# FadeIn with css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<textarea id="text" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea> <span id="fade">fade</span>

$("#fade").click(function () {  
    $("#text").fadeIn(31000, function () {   
        $("#text").css('background-color', 'red');         
    });      
    return false;    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tG7xE/

Why in this example fadeIn doesnt working? How can i make it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery fade in background colour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652281/jquery-fade-in-background-colour)

Comment: Because the textarea is already visible. You can only fade it in if it is hidden.

Comment: If you wish to fade in a background colour, then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967815/how-do-you-fade-in-out-a-background-color-using-jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jQuery-UI and then execute your code like this:

```
$("#fade").click(function() {
  $('#text').animate({backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}, 'slow');
});​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tG7xE/11/) is an updated version of your fiddle.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, is possible manipulate values from? for example 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tG7xE/5/

```
<textarea style="display:none;" id="text" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea> <span id="fade">fade</span>
```

​

```
$("#fade").click(function () {  
    $("#text").fadeIn(function () {   
        $("#text").css('background-color', 'red');         
    });      
    return false;    
}); ​
```

`fadeIn` works only if element is not visible to hide it use `fadeOut()` or `hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

I do think you expect to work `fadeIn` differently from what it actually does. It's not used to fade in the background color, but to fade in a hidden element. In case you set your `textarea`'s `display` to `none` (like in: http://jsfiddle.net/tG7xE/4/) you'll see what I mean. After the fadeIn is complete the specified callback is executed (bg turns red).

In case you want to animate background colors I think you should have a look at jQuery UI's possibilities to animate color values: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: @Mike Noshys: Read the second part of the answer, it's just that you won't be able to use `fadeIn` for what you are trying to do.